# Loading module from “website.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, github, vite

I have followed this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yo2bMGnIKE8

my github repository file is located at ..\WPL\WalnutCoding\WalnutCoding
so the codes i had to run from the tutorial where the next

git add walnutcoding\dist -f
git commit -m"new"
git subtree push --prefix walnutcoding\dist origin gh-pages

this is the repository adress https://github.com/jasperorens/WalnutCoding

and this should be the website it is build upon https://jasperorens.github.io/WalnutCoding/

the build is succesfull apperently, but it's still not showing anything, so I assume there is an issue with the base I've set in my vite.config.ts, <- typescript

this is the vite.config.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/WalnutCoding/',
  build:{
    rollupOptions:{
      external:[
        'src/assets/0509me.jpg',
          'src/assets/WC.png',
          'src/assets/CC.jpg',
      ]
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  }
})
```

I have no idea what's wrong

I have tried changing the name, using an other repository to see if the changes to the base get effected but alas

Comment: I also have changed vite.config.ts with a rewritten vite.config.js which did not solve it also